# Java workgroup and AD security

Tags: java, security, active-directory, dns, certificate

I'm building an application that interacts with a CMS Platform. In turn, that platform might be integrated against an AD Server, or a Windows Domain (e.g. workgroup).

In my code, what I need is to secure the access to the platform's api. I'll explain my logic:

1. The application interacts with the web service.
2. The web service verifies the identity of the user. (I don't want to ask the user for it's user/password combo)
3. The web service performs various tasks regarding with the platform's API.

So, in step 2, what should I use? Certificates are not an option. If I was in an intranet with thousands of users, thousands of certificates would have to be created. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Ok, certificates are not an option. I forgot to mention that if I was in an intranet with thousands of users, thousands of certificates would've to be created. Aare there alternatives?

Comment: Do you mean 'in step **2**' ?

Comment: Yes. How can I make sure it's a legitimate user contacting the Web Service?

Comment: For the Active Directory part, I guess I could verify the identity with both the username and it's domain. But what about workgroups?